# Testing Key Assumptions of Cultural Psychology with Bayesian Analysis

Tags: bayesian, assumptions, bugs

I have been trying to come up with a way to represent some of the key assumptions of culture in actual measurement and statistical modeling practices. For all of these points, it seems like the Frequentist Approach is too fixed and not fluid enough to capture the underlying structure of this evasive and ambiguous construct. I was wondering if a Bayesian approach would be more suitable to help me account for our theoretical understanding of this process.

Here are three assumptions of culture that I am trying to incorporate:

1. (a) Individuals within a culture group ascribe to a specific value to a varying degree, and that the degree is different not just between individuals but (b) within.
2. Culture is dynamic. The degree to which a specific value is endorsed vary as a function of situations, time, and trends.
3. Culture is interactive. (a) The degree to which a value is endorsed interacts with the degree another value is endorsed. Likewise, (b) by strongly endorsing a certain value at time 1, it increases the likelihood to endorse the value at time 2 (recursive).

For instance, let's say that we are measuring the cultural value of 'individual competence' among European Americans. Out of a group of 100 individuals, some of those individuals will ascribe to this value more than others (Assumption 1a), and this endorsement of valuing 'individual competence' is not fixed, but will vary within the person as well (Assumption 1b). Moreover, given that culture is dynamic, this group of 100 individuals' overall orientation to this value will increase, decrease, or remain stable over time (Assumption 2). Finally, this group change occurs through individual endorsements or lack of endorsements of the value in relationship to how that value reinforces itself (Assumption 3b) or interactions with other values (Assumption 3a).

A simple (non-informed) Bayesian Model that estimates the degree to which a given value is endorsed looks like this in the BUGS language:

```
model {
 #Likelihood
 for (i in 1:N){
  y[i] ~ dnorm(mu, tau)
 }
 #Priors
 mu ~ dunif(-1e10,1e10)
 sigma ~ dunif(0, 100)
 tau <- pow(sigma, -2)
}
```

Is there any way I can add to this model in order to include (not necessarily test) the assumptions I mentioned earlier? For instance, could I edit the model to include distributions for the 100 individuals instead of just the overall group (Assumption 1b; to demonstrate that there is a degree of variance that each person endorses the value and that this degree of variance could impact the degree to which the entire groups endorses the value.)

Or, could I write in a function that includes my belief that those who endorse a relatively higher degree of this value are more likely to endorse the value as much or higher in the future, and those who endorse it to a lower degree are more likely to endorse it the same or less in the future (Assumption 3b)?

If anyone would be willing to offer suggestions, thoughts, or opinions, I would be very grateful.

Thank you for sharing your knowledge and expertise.

EDIT:

In accordance to the helpful comments I have received, I would like to clarify that I am open to both simulation studies and data driven models. I am more familiar with data driven models, so I had originally framed the question toward that end. However, based on the comments, it seems like simulation studies might be more appropriate.

If anyone would be willing to address specific elements required for modeling my three assumptions, I would really appreciate it. I will direct my reading based on what you recommend.

Again, my greatest appreciation for your help and direction.

Comment: This sounds more like a simulation than a data-based, empirical model to me. Frequentist models do have the "limitation" that they require empirically observation information and data for estimation. Bayesian approaches don't necessarily share this limitation and would be a possible avenue to pursue but, in my opinion, agent-based models (ABMs) would be a better, more widely used approach to developing simulations.

Comment: I agree with @DJohnson, it is not clear if you are interested in Bayesian data-driven model or simulation study. Please edit to clarify, because otherwise it is not clear what you are asking, what makes the question unanswerable.

Comment: @DJohnson,Thank you for introducing the prospect of doing a simulation study. I will be looking into agent-based modeling as a potential option to include the major assumptions of this theory. Also, Tim, Thank you for helping me clarify and improve my question. Please find my edits above.

Comment: I wonder just how far you could get with [multilevel models](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model) - "Frequentist Approach is too fixed and not fluid enough to capture the underlying structure" sounds rather pessimistic to me. (If you don't like fixed effects, there are random effects instead...)